# C/C++ - Punteros

Tags: c++, c

Tengo una duda sobre el siguiente código:

```
int main()
{
    int *x, *y;
    int i;
    i = 10;
    x = &i;
    y = x;
    *x = *y +1;
    cout << i << endl;
    *y = *x + 1;
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Siempre que tengo que representar punteros que apuntan a otros punteros y estos a una variable, para luego modificaría por ejemplo, imagino un diagrama de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al ver el otro día apuntes de la facultad noté que el profesor lo había dispuesto de manera diferente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que no entiendo es como pueden apuntar las dos a la misma variable si *y apunta a otro puntero.

Comment: `x` es igual al puntero de `i`, `y` recibe el puntero de `i` ya que `x` era igual al puntero de `i`... la representación de tu profesor está bien...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los punteros son variables que en vez de almacenar datos al uso almacenan posiciones de memoria. Así, si tu tienes esto:

```
int *x, *y;
int i = 10;
```

El programa tendrá algo así:

```
x -> (posición aleatoria)
y -> (posición aleatoria)
i -> 10
```

Si ahora el programa se encuentra con esto:

```
x = &i;
```

Que queda claro que la intención es almacenar la dirección de memoria de `i` en `x`, las variables quedarán así:

```
x -> dirección de i
y -> (posición aleatoria)
i -> 10
```

Y al ejecutar finalmente esto:

```
y = x;
```

Que lo que hace es copiar en `y` la posición de memoria almacenada en `x`, las variables quedan tal que:

```
x -> dirección de i
y -> dirección de i
i -> 10
```

Piensa que para que un puntero apunte a su vez a otro puntero, este primer puntero debería ser doble:

```
int **y;
```

Lo único que indica el puntero anterior es que internamente almacena una dirección de memoria... y que si vas a dicha posición te encontrarás con otra dirección de memoria y finalmente en esta segunda posición de memoria se encontrará un dato de tipo entero.

Comment: Entonces si tengo `n` punteros apuntándose consecutivamente, necesitaré escribir `n` asteriscos, cierto?

Comment: @EduardoS. Lo normal es usar punteros y punteros dobles... pocas veces te encontrarás punteros triples y, al menos yo, jamás he visto un puntero cuádruple. Pero sí,  para un puntero normal, un asterisco y para un puntero doble, dos asteriscos y así

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias =)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que crees que cuando tienes por ejemplo: 
`int *x, *y, i = 45;
x = &i;
y = x;`


***y*** apunta a ***x*** pero no es asi.

Explicacion: Un puntero es una variable. Como variable tiene su propia dirección de memoria. Esa variable puntero es especial por que no recibe valores en si, sino la dirección física de la memoria que esta usando una variable que no es un puntero. Ahora con el * sacamos el valor de la dirección de memoria que tiene una variable puntero. pero que pasa si `y = x;` ***y*** no tiene la dirección de ***x***, mas bien tiene la dirección a la que apunta ***x***, por lo tanto tanto ***x*** como ***y*** apuntan la misma dirección de memoria, ahora para decir que ***y*** apunto a ***x***, ***y*** tiene que ser otro tipo de puntero en este caso `int**` para que apunte a ***x***, pero la asignación debería ser asi: `y = &x;` donde ***y*** es `int **y;`


En Resumen: 
 int* apunta a variables normales,
 int** apunta a int*,
 int*** apunta a int**,
 int**** apunta a int***

y asi sucesivamente hasta que te aburras de poner *, y recorda todo puntero tiene su propia dirección de memoria que puede ser apuntada por otro puntero de nivel superior y este puede apuntar a memoria de nivel inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Los punteros en C++ sirven para señalar objetos, y también para manipularlos. Obviamente eso ya lo sabes jeje
Y se usan dos formas:
 * 
como tu ejemplo: int *x. "el asterisco *" nos dice: "objeto apuntado por" y nos permite obtener el valor referenciado por dicha dirección.
 &i
"el ampersand &" nos dice: "dirección de" y nos permite obtener la dirección de memoria de una variable cualquiera.

Entonces para averiguar la dirección de memoria de cualquier objeto usaremos el operador de dirección (&) y para manipular el objeto apuntado por un puntero usaremos el operador de indirección, que es un asterisco (*)

Answer (score 0):

Estás representando dos situaciones distintas, en el primer gráfico representas un puntero `y` que apunta a otro puntero `x` (que a su vez apunta a un int `i`); en este caso se puede decir brevemente que "y es un puntero a puntero" y algunos llaman a `y`un "puntero doble.

Mientras que en el segundo gráfico representas a dos punteros (`x` e `y`) que ambos apuntan al mismo int `i`. Y es esa la relación entre x - y - i que se muestra en el código de tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Los punteros son simplemente enteros del tamaño del bus de datos del microprocesador.

Por ejemplo en micro arquitecturas x86 `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)` , esto quiere decir que un puntero es simplemente un entero (sin signo).
En micro arquitecturas x86_64 `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(void*)` (Para el compilador MSVC)

Para que entiendas mejor, cambiemos un poco el programa

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long x, y; // x e y son enteros sin signo de 64-bit
    int i; 
    i = 10; 
    x = (unsigned long long) &i; // x es igual a la dirección en memoria de i
    y = x;  // y es igual a x (y por ende a la dirección en memoria de i)
    *((int*)x) = *((int*)y) + 1; // se reinterpretan las dirección contenidas por x e y
                                // como direcciones a enteros, y se desreferencian
    cout << i << endl;

    *((int*)y) = *((int*)x) + 1; // lo mismo que el comentario de arriba
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

En C++ el type checking es poco flexible comparado con el type checking de C, así que por desgracia hay que hacer casting explícito de un tipo `void*` a `unsigned long long`

El anterior programa es totalmente equivalente al siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    void *x, *y; // x e y son punteros
    int i; 
    i = 10; 
    x = &i; // x es igual a la dirección en memoria de i
    y = x;  // y es igual a x (y por ende a la dirección en memoria de i)
    *((int*)x) = *((int*)y) + 1; // se reinterpretan las dirección contenidas por x e y
                                // como direcciones a enteros, y se desreferencian
    cout << i << endl;

    *((int*)y) = *((int*)x) + 1; // lo mismo que el comentario de arriba
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora la pregunta del millón es: *Si x e y son punteros por qué necesito castearlos a `int*`*. En realidad el casteo se debe a que el compilador debe ir a la memoria a la que apunta la variable y extraer cierta cantidad de bytes a partir de éste.

A la hora de querer acceder a la memoria apuntada por algún puntero del tipo `void*` se debe especificar el tamaño de la zona a extraer. El compilador es bastante inteligente, si tu declaras un puntero como `int*` él sabe que debe ir y extraer `sizeof(int)` bytes a la dirección contenida en `i` y tratar la memoria extraida como objetos del tipo `int`. No obstante esto no tiene nada que ver con punteros, los punteros son simplemente enteros. El tener distintos tipos de punteros es simplemente para ayudar al compilador en su ardua tarea de transformar código fuente en código máquina.

Comment: Esto es un talento innato para complicar las cosas.