# C/C++ - Punteros (Heap y Stack)

Tags: c++

Hace una semanas hice una [pregunta sobre punteros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129278/c-c-punteros?noredirect=1#comment241125_129278).

Ahora tengo otra que creo involucra al Heap y el Stack.

El código es el siguiente:

```
int main()
{
    int *x; int *y;
    int w;
    x = new int();
    w = 85;
    *x = w;
    y = x;
    w++;
    cout << *y;
    return 0;
}
```

Y yo me imaginé que la relación entre `*y`, `*x` y `w` era como este diagrama que había hecho antes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, en el último Console Out cuándo muestro por pantalla lo que tiene lo apuntado por `y` (`*y`) sale 85 y no 86 como pensaba.

Imagino que tiene que ver con la sentencia:

```
x = new int();
```

Pero, ¿Dónde apunta `x`? ¿No debería cambiar luego de?:

```
*x = w;
```

¿Hay más ejercicios extras sobre problemas similares?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si suponemos que el estado inicial del programa es el siguiente:

```
variable  posición de memoria   valor
w         0x1000                (aleatorio)
x         0x1004                (aleatorio)
y         0x1008                (aleatorio)
```

Con la siguiente instrucción:

```
x = new int();
```

Estás reservando 4 bytes para almacenar un entero... y la reserva queda apuntada por el puntero `x`. El estado de la aplicación queda así:

```
variable  posición de memoria   valor
w         0x1000                (aleatorio)
x         0x1004                0xA000
y         0x1008                (aleatorio)
---       0xA000                (aleatorio)
```

La siguiente instrucción:

```
w = 85;
```

Almacena en la variable `w` el valor 85... sin problemas.

```
variable  posición de memoria   valor
w         0x1000                85
x         0x1004                0xA000
y         0x1008                (aleatorio)
---       0xA000                (aleatorio)
```

Pasamos a la siguiente instrucción:

```
*x = w;
```

Aquí no estás haciendo que `x` apunte a `w`, sino que estás copiando el valor almacenado en `w` en la memoria apuntada por `x`, que recordemos que es una posición aleatoria de memoria reservada con `new`.

```
variable  posición de memoria   valor
w         0x1000                85
x         0x1004                0xA000
y         0x1008                (aleatorio)
---       0xA000                85
```

Pasamos a la siguiente instrucción:

```
y = x;
```

Ahora haces que el puntero `y` apunte a la misma memoria que `x`... que es la memoria reservada con `new`.

```
variable  posición de memoria   valor
w         0x1000                85
x         0x1004                0xA000
y         0x1008                0xA000
---       0xA000                85
```

Podemos continuar:

```
w++;
```

Incrementas `w`... pero ningún puntero está apuntando a esta posición de memoria...

```
variable  posición de memoria   valor
w         0x1000                86
x         0x1004                0xA000
y         0x1008                0xA000
---       0xA000                85
```

Y, finalmente:

```
cout << *y;
```

Con esta instrucción imprimes el valor almacenado en la memoria reservada con `new`, que recordmos que se corresponde con el valor inicial de `w`, es decir, 85.

Para conseguir la relación que indicas en la imagen tu programa tendría que quedar más bien así:

```
int main()
{
    int *x; int *y;
    int w;
    // x = new int(); <<--- esto sobra
    w = 85;
    // *x = w; <<--- ya no se copia el valor de w
    x = &w; // <<--- sino su dirección de memoria
    y = x; // Ahora y apunta a w
    w++;
    cout << *y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, yo agregaría los tiempos de vida en cada forma...

Comment: @nikomaster todo muere más o menos a la vez al finalizar el programa... y además eso no afecta en nada a la pregunta, por eso no he dicho nada al respecto

Answer (score 8):

> ¿Dónde apunta `x`?

Vamos paso por paso.

#### `int *x; int *y;`

Crea dos punteros a entero (`int *`) y no les asigna valor, así pues apuntan a un lugar indeterminado.

[image: int *x; int *y;]

---

#### `int w;`

Crea un entero (`int`) y no le asigna valor, así pues contiene un valor indeterminado.

[image: int w;]

---

#### `x = new int();`

Crea un nuevo puntero a entero (`int *`) que apunta a un valor entero (`int`) en memoria dinámica, este entero recién creado tiene un valor indeterminado. Almacena el puntero creado en el puntero a entero `x`, dicho puntero pierde su valor anterior.

[image: x = new int();]

---

#### `w = 85;`

Asigna el valor `85` a la variable entera `w`, dicha variable pierde su valor anterior.

[image: w = 85;]

---

#### `*x = w;`

Asigna el valor contenido en la variable `w` al entero al que apunta el puntero a entero `x`. Al puntero `x` hace dos pasos se le hizo apuntar a un entero en memoria dinámica creado mediante `new int()`, ahora dicho entero (apuntado por `x`) copia el valor de `w`, que será `85`.

[image: *x = w;]

---

#### `y = x;`

Asigna el valor contenido en el puntero a entero `x` al puntero a entero `y`. El puntero a entero `y` pierde su valor anterior y ahora apunta al mismo sitio que `x` que será  un entero en memoria dinámica creado mediante `new int()` hace tres pasos, dicho entero (apuntado tanto por `x` como por `y`) contiene `85`.

[image: y = x]

---

#### `w++;`

Incrementa el valor contenido en la variable `w`, dicho valor es `85` por lo que pasará a ser `86`.

[image: w++]

---

#### `cout << *y;`

Muestra por consola el valor contenido en el puntero a entero `y`, dicho puntero apunta al mismo sitio que `x` que será un entero en memoria dinámica creado mediante `new int()` hace cinco pasos y que contiene `85`.

[image: y = x]